# C# How to find two different strings at one search in RichTextbox

Tags: search, richtextbox

I have a lot of Android log in RichTextbox loaded from file. 
Lets say i search for "Fatal" word by default search method and i got this:

```
10-11 19:37:44.647 19525 19789 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[ContactSaveService]
```

But, as I know there is possibility that there will be more than 1 exception in dumpstate. 
So i thought, it would be nice to compare file name with line of Fatal in this log.

File name: dumpstate_app_201210111708___error

Error log: 10-11 19:37:44.647

It doesnt match. 
So i would like to do something like this:

```
    if(rtb.Lines[i].contains(date_of_exception))
{

    rtb.Select(startPos, text.Length);
    rtb.ScrollToCaret();
    rtb.Focus();

}
```

Of course it doesnt work. I have no idea how to solve it. 
I thought about getting number of line with found text and search if this line contains date_of_exception

What I am sure. Time of fatal exception must be the same with time in file name. And that's why i need to check if line in richtextbox contains "fatal" word and time of exception from file name.

I hope it is clear, if not, i will try to describe it better. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be more specific?